# Make netcat a "stream"

Tags: networking, netcat

So, I'm doing a simple experiment with `netcat` where you can set up a voice call. Here are the commands I'm using.

server:
`arecord | netcat -l 10000 | aplay`

client:
`arecord | netcat localhost 10000 | aplay`

My issue here is that when the server starts a couple seconds before the client connects, the voice is delayed from the server. I am wondering how I can remove this delay. I'm pretty sure I just need to set some values in `netcat`, but I'm not sure which ones to set.

I have used UDP and TCP. Both don't make a difference.

Comment: Maybe use `socat` rather than `netcat`?

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect your shell buffers `arecord` output before `netcat` is able to pass it further (which is when the client connects). To confirm, try:

```
arecord | pv | netcat -l 10000 | aplay
```

In my Ubuntu `pv` shows that `arecord` produces at least about 60 KiB of output (it takes about 8 seconds) even if there is no connection to `netcat`. You may suspect this buffer is implemented by `pv` but it does not depend on `pv -B` option, so I think it's the shell's buffer for the pipe.

I tried with `stdbuf` and `unbuffer` (the latter from `expect-dev` package in my Ubuntu) but the results were unsatisfying.

I achieved significant improvement when I used `dd` to flush enough data **on the client side**:

```
arecord | netcat localhost 10000 | { dd bs=100K count=1 iflag=fullblock of=/dev/null; aplay; }
```

In my case `100K` was enough; your millage may vary. Note that you will have to wait several seconds for `dd` to finish if you run the command too soon (before the buffer is full on the server side) or if the `bs=…` parameter is way too big.

Comment: There's also `-I` for `nc` TCP receive buffer, and `-O` for send.

Answer (score 0):

When using TCP, the connection is "guaranteed" not to lose data. In your case you probably don't want this, as the only way your client and server can avoid losing data is to queue it pending delivery.

With two systems you can switch to using UDP. Since this is connectionless you don't get your first packets queued, but they do get discarded. I can't test this out at the moment but I would suggest you try this:

Server on system 1

```
arecord | nc -u -l -p 10000 | aplay
```

Client on system 2

```
arecord | nc -u system1 10000 | aplay
```

Comment: I had already tried udp.

Comment: @SpecialBomb please update your question to explain this, and what (presumably) didn't work

Comment: @SpecialBomb so  please update your answer, because roaima is right, and anyone reading your question will say the same to use UDP.